# Javascript match anything until pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

Given `example-123`, I need to extract just `example`. Also `example` could be: `example-example-345`, in which case I need `example-example`. This is the pattern I'm looking for:

```
> str.match('-[0-9]{1,}$')[0]
'-123'
```

I tried:

```
str.match(/(.*)-[0-9]{1,}$/)
'example-123'
```

and

```
str.match(/(?s).*)-[0-9]{1,}$/)[0]
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?s).*)-[0-9]{1,}$/: Invalid group
```

and

```
str.match('[^-[0-9]{1,}$]')
null
```

and

```
str.match('(.*)[^-[0-9]{1,}$]')
null
```

and

```
str.match('/.*/[^-[0-9]{1,}$]')
null
```

and

```
str.match('.*^(-[0-9]{1,}$)')
null
```

... the list goes on

Comment: `"example"` is a placeholder for what? A string comprised of: a) any characters other than hyphens?; b) lowercase letters? c) letters? d) letters and digits; e) word characters? What would you want returned if the string were `"dog-cat-345"` (as opposed to `"dog-dog-345"`)?

Comment: Anything means anything that can come before a `-[0-9]{1,}$` pattern which includes everything from `a)`-`e)`. In which case `dog-cat` and `dog-dog` respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
str.match(/^(.+)-\d+$/)[1]
```

**matching everything till a hyphen followed by numbers!**

And with `[1]` it will get the first part only!

Comment: *"Try this"* Why? What is it? How does it work? Code dumps aren't *useful* answers. Please explain the pattern and how it solves the OP's problem.

Comment: It's regular expression! how can I explain that? it's exactlly OP wants! matching everything till a hyphen followed by numbers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [positive lookahead](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind) for that:

```js
let str = 'example-example-123';
console.log(str.match(/.+(?=-123)/)[0]);

str = "example-123";
console.log(str.match(/.+(?=-123)/)[0]);

str = "example-example-example-123-something-after";
console.log(str.match(/.+(?=-123)/)[0]);
```

Comment: The 3rd example's result should be `example-example-example-123-something-after` not `example-example-example` because I'm only interested in strings ended with the pattern.

Comment: this only matches -123 at the end

Comment: @nlblack323 - In that case, shouldn't it be `null` rather than `example-example-example-123-something-after`?

Comment: yeah yeah, it should be null, that's what I meant

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*?` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy, none greedy match)

```js
const str = 'example-example-123';

console.log(str.match(/(.*?)-\d/)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match the regular expression

```
^([a-z]+)(?:-\1)*(?=-)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T0ZPLs/1)

I have assumed the word preceding the first hyphen must contain only lowercase letters. That assumption may be faulty, of course, in which case `([a-z]+)` would have to be changed accordingly. To match a letter followed by zero or more letters and numbers, for example, it would be `([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)`.

---

As shown at the link, the text indicated below by the party hats was matched.

```
example-123
^^^^^^^

example-example-345
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

dog-dog-dog-123
^^^^^^^^^^^

dog-dog-cat-123
^^^^^^^

dog-cat-cat 123
^^^^^^^^^^^

dog-dog123
^^^

dog
```

There is no match in the last example.

---

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^         Match beginning of the string
(         Begin capture group 1
  [a-z]+  Match one or more lowercase letters
)         End capture group 1
(?:       Begin non-capture group
  -\1     Match a hyphen followed by the contents of capture group 1
)*        End the non-capture group and execute it zero or more times
(?=       Begin a positive lookahead
  -       Match a hyphen
)         End the positive lookahead
```

Note that the positive lookahead `(?=-)` forces the match to be followed by a hyphen but that hyphen is not part of the match that is returned.

Comment: if you try : `ex21-ri25-125` it will not match!

Comment: and with lookahead you are causing performance issues in long use!

Comment: @Ali, `"ex21-ri25-125"` does not match because `"ex21"` does not match `[a-z]+`. See my discussion of that. I would remove the lookahead if you can tell me how to do so. I could of course remove it and chop of the hyphen at the end in a separate step but I don't think the OP is looking for that.